# Can't Get Subtitles to Format Correctly

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, subtitles

I currently have a video file (MKV) and a subtitle file (WebVTT). The subtitles are not formatted well as they don't move to appropriate locations and the text is much too big. I converted the subtitles to an ASS file to make editing easier -- since ASS supports defining format definitions by name -- but none of the edits I make change the way it is rendered. When I load the MKV into VLC and select the local ASS file, the subtitles are always the big white default text, no matter if I change the color, font or size. I also tried converting my ASS file to SRT as well as the MKV to MP4, but neither of the combinations changed anything. I've also tried embedding the subtitles into the video using ffmpeg, but it still renders then same when played. Any thoughts as to what is forcing the default formatting?

As a quick summary of the software involved:

os: Ubuntu

player: VLC

containers: MKV, MP4

subtitles: ASS, SRT

editor: ffmpeg

Comment: Sorry guys, this appears to be a VLC bug. I saw some stuff on it from 5 years ago, but hardly thought they could still be relevant. I guess mplayer is the solution.

Comment: Works for me as expected with VLC 3.0.8. Provide your subtitles file.